# Codeigniter redirect No direct script access allowed

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I am working on a clients project that has a third party script integrated. I need to be able to redirect from one of its view php files back to one of my controllers.

So I tried to simply put `redirect($leads_url , 'refresh')`  but I because I am using `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');` on the controller I am redirecting to it is being blocked.

Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have spent more time looking over my problem.  I am also using Bonfire and it uses `<?php defined('BASEPATH') || exit('No direct script access allowed');` instead of the other line of code above.  This one works like I hoped, but not sure why.